# Facebook Graph API : Some requests return an ampty data array

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I hope someone wil be able to help to resolve my problem.
We can't say Facebook's forums are very useful for developers...

This is my problem.
On two different applications, I execute requests with Graph API.
For one of both, I make a friends request to invite user's friends to use application.
For the second application, I use Facebook Places to retrieve all informations about a location.
These two codes are simples functionnalities tests.

Before excute a request with Graph API, I ask to user to give me necessaries authorizations.
But results are, often, an empty JSON "**data**" array...

Before posting here, I search some solutions on internet.
Some people say application hasn't necessaries rights. Others user must like application page to retrieve informations correctly...
I tried these solutions... whithout concluant result.

For example, talking about my Facebook Place based application.
It asks user_checkins and friends_checkins rights.
Goal is to retrieve, for a given location, datas from users who're tagged there.
But I have an empty **data** array as return.

I tried my code in different ways, with PHP SDK, Javscript SDK and FQL. Same result.

Thanks :)

*Sorry for my english. I'm a french developper ;)*

Comment: could it be that there is no data to be returned? Hence the empty array?

Answer (score 1):

For this - "Goal is to retrieve, for a given location, datas from users who're tagged there." Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/ and you will see that you can only get the checkin information for the current user or friend of the current user. In the case of a friend you will only get that information if the friend has allowed other apps to see this. So to test that you get data you should check in to a place (page), find the place's id, then make a query to https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/checkins with an access token that has user_checkins permission.

Also, here is a tool that you may find useful when debugging your API calls and permissions - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer